# .Net 2.0 Ping failing in long running system. Windows Ping succeeds

Tags: c#, .net, windows-xp, .net-2.0

I have a .Net 2.0 application written in C# that monitors other Windows XP Computers on a local LAN.  On some systems, after a long uptime (40 to 120 days) the .Net Ping can fail.  Windows command-prompt ping still succeeds.

Once this failure has occurred, it appears that all .Net Pings fail.  A separate .Net application using similar code also fails.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
internal static bool canPingHost(string host)
{
    bool success = false;
    const int PING_TIMEOUT_MS = 1000;
    try
    {
       using (Ping p = new Ping())
       {
            PingReply pr = p.Send(host, PING_TIMEOUT_MS);
            if (pr.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                success = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {                
    }
    return success;
}
```

Key points about the setup for this issue:

- All PCs are plugged in to the same unmanaged switch
- All other PCs can use the same .Net Ping to talk to the problem system.
- Windows ping works correctly on the problem system.
- Any .Net 2.0 application tried on the on problem system fails.
- Database operations to and from the problem system also work (TCP connection)
- Stopping and starting the application does not fix the issue on the problem system.

When this system fails, I've run another application with further debugging information.

```
static string doping(IPAddress IP)
{
    int PING_TIMEOUT_MS = 3000;
    string rv = IP.ToString();

    using (Ping p = new Ping())
    {
        bool success = false;
        PingReply pr = null;
        try
        {
            pr = p.Send(IP, PING_TIMEOUT_MS);
            success = pr.Status == IPStatus.Success;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            rv = rv +" [ " +ex.Message + " ] ";
        }

        if (pr != null)
        {
            if (success)
            {
                rv = rv + " yes " + pr.RoundtripTime.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                rv = rv + " no " + pr.Status.ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            rv = rv + " no (fail) ";
        }
    }
    return rv;
}
```

The output from the program is `192.168.0.2 no 1450`.
The `PingReply` Status variable returns **1450** which does not appear to be defined in the `IPStatus` (`PingReply.Status`) enum.

After restarting the problem computer, .Net Ping starts to work correctly again

It looks like there is a resource problem of some description.  I'm not sure which resource it could be.

I have read about issues with asynchronous Pings and .Net 2.0.  This is a synchronous ping and as far as I can tell it is not affected.

I'm looking for:

- Prevention of the problem in the first place
- Suggestions to debug the remote system once it fails (production system, Windows XP SP3, no developer tools installed)
- Monitoring resources to determine which one is failing.

Caveats:

- Rebooting the problem system on a regular basis is not currently an option.
- Upgraded to the latest version of the .Net Framework is not currently an option.
- Changing the software to no longer use .Net Ping is an option but I would still like to know what is going on.

Comment: You could start by not just catching and swallowing exceptions. There could very easily be an exception being thrown which explains what's going on extremely clearly - but you'd never know, because you're ignoring it without even logging.

Comment: 1450 = ERROR_NO_SYSTEM_RESOURCES in Windows error codes - not sure if that'd make it into the PingReply.Status enumeration or not though.

Comment: It sounds very similar to the ol' Windows98 max uptime issue of 48 odd days.

Comment: @JonSkeet:  The additional application run after failure does catch the exceptions.  No exception is being thrown, The PingReply variable is being returned normally.

Comment: @Rup: No System Resources.  That's Interesting.  Do you have any idea which resource would be lacking?

Comment: @leppie: Uptime is inconsistent.  The error has been discovered with uptimes of  35, 40 and 101 days.

Comment: @lnical: Do you have such a machine up? try running `netstat` or use Process Explorer to see what is happening with the .NET runtime if possible.

Comment: @leppie:  No systems with the problem available at the moment.  `netstat -an` showed an expected  number of connections and listening services (10-15 active connections)

Comment: @JonSkeet: I've added the additional diagnostic Ping snippet to the original question which has error handling.

Comment: @lnical: But why don't you add exception logging in the normal flow? Why would you want to lose that information?

Comment: @JonSkeet:  Adding the exception logging in the normal flow is something that I will do in future revisions of the software.  That will need to go through a full QA / Release cycle which takes time.  The diagnostic software is quick utility just created to help debug this particular issue and is easily changed and deployed ad-hoc.

Comment: any final solution with full source code?

Comment: @Kiquenet: Please see the solution below.  The ping issue in my case turned out to be caused by  **another application on the system**.  The source code was not modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was another application running on the same system that was consuming vast quantities (> 100 MB) of **Pool nonpaged Bytes**.  This happened over a period of several weeks.

This was determined by looking at the Performance counters for the entire system.  The ones that stood out were:

- Memory, Pool Nonpaged Bytes (which covers the entire computer)
- Process, _Total, Pool Nonpaged Bytes (which appears to cover all running process)
- Process, Pool Nonpaged Bytes for each running process on the system.

Pool Nonpaged bytes stood out as a very large number, all concentrated in one application

Restarting the other application caused the Non-Paged Pool memory usage to return to a much lower value.  Ping then completed successfully.  The lack of Non Paged Pool memory appeared to cause the Ping failure.

Information on the Pool Nonpaged bytes can be found on the page [Pushing the Limits of Windows: Paged and Nonpaged Pool](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/03/26/3211216.aspx). When the system runs out of Nonpaged bytes many resource allocations can be denied leading to an exceedingly unstable system.

Very unusual issue.  The resolution did not have anything directly involved with the Ping source.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't look much different than what I used for a ping checking mechanism.  I've never had an issue, but it seems that yours is outside of the application realm altogether.  I'd say either a buggy network card driver or the IP stack is corrupted somehow.

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        using (var ping = new Ping())
        using (var waiter = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset))
        {
            var options = new PingOptions { DontFragment = true };
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            var data = now.ToLongDateString() + " " + now.ToLongTimeString();
            var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            const int Timeout = 120;

            ping.PingCompleted += PingCompleted;
            ping.SendAsync("www.speedtest.net", Timeout, buffer, options, waiter);
            waiter.WaitOne();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the Ping Completed event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingCompletedEventArgs"/> instance containing
    /// the event data.</param>
    private static void PingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Address: {0}", e.Reply.Address);
            Console.WriteLine("RoundTrip time: {0}", e.Reply.RoundtripTime);
            Console.WriteLine("Time to live: {0}", e.Reply.Options.Ttl);
            Console.WriteLine("Don't fragment: {0}", e.Reply.Options.DontFragment);
            Console.WriteLine("Buffer size: {0}", e.Reply.Buffer.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("Buffer: {0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Reply.Buffer));
        }
        else if (e.Error != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Error);
        }

        var waitHandle = e.UserState as EventWaitHandle;

        if (waitHandle != null)
        {
            waitHandle.Set();
        }
    }
```